# Localization of Ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the justification for the last sentence of this theorem (http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JA). I do not understand how they can say, "each $Ae_i$ is a ring". It is not a ring, it is an ideal generated by $e_i$, so the isomorphism does not make sense. Unless they mean, the localization of $A$ with respect to the multiplicative set $S = \{ e_i^m ~ | ~ m\geq 0\} = \{ 1, e_i\}$. But even in that case, I do not see why the isomorphism follows, and why, as I am assuming they are trying to imply, $Ae_i = A_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$.

Comment: $Ae_i$ is a ring with unity $e_i$. This is arguably confusing and authors should point it out.

Comment: @darij When you say, "ring with unity", you mean the localization of $A$ with respect to $e_i$? This is what I thought it means. The notation is non-standard.

Comment: No, I mean $Ae_i$ -- that is, the ideal of $A$ generated by $e_i$. It has unity $e_i$ because each $b \in A$ satisfies $be_i e_i = be_i$.

Comment: @darij Can you explain where the isomorphisms come from, as mentioned on StackProject.

Comment: Which isomorphisms?

Comment: @darij Dear mr Darij. First, $A = \prod Ae_i$. Second, $Ae_i = A_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$.

Comment: First of all, it is $R$, not $A$, in the current version of the link. To show the isomorphism $R \cong \prod_i Re_i$, consider the map $R \to \prod_i Re_i$ that sends each $a \in R$ to the family $\left(a \mod Re_i\right)_{i}$ (where $a \mod I$ means the residue class of $a$ modulo any ideal $I$). This is a ring homomorphism. To prove that it is an isomorphism, notice that the map $\prod_i Re_i \to R, \  \left(x_i\right)_{i} \mapsto \sum_i x_i e_i$ is an inverse.

Comment: Actually, no, I'm not sure of my argument. I assumed that the $e_i$ are a complete system of orthogonal idempotents (that is, $e_ie_j = \delta_{i,j} e_i$, and $\sum_i e_i = 1$), but this is nowhere said. Maybe it follows from their definition, but I don't see how.

Comment: What we do have, though, is that $e_i e_j \equiv \delta_{i,j} e_i \mod I$ and $\sum_i e_i \equiv 1 \mod I$. In particular, $\sum_i e_i - 1 \in I$ is nilpotent, whence $\sum_i e_i$ is invertible. Maybe this is of some use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no localization involved.

The ring $S=R/I$ is a product of fields, so $S=\prod_{i=1}^n S\bar{e}_i$ for some idempotents $\bar{e}_1,\dots,\bar{e}_n\in S$.

Lemma 10.31.5 tells you that there is a bijection between the idempotents in $R$ and in $S$ (given by the canonical projection). So we can assume that $\bar{e}_i=e_i+I$, where $e_i$ is an idempotent in $R$.

It's now sufficient to prove that $R=\prod_{i=1}^n Re_i$.

Note that if $R$ is commutative and $e=e^2\in R$, then $Re$ is a ring with the induced operations and $e$ as a unit (so not a subring of $R$, in general).

Comment: Localization is involved -- it appears in the statement of the Lemma. I still don't see how $R = \prod_{i=1}^n Re_i$ is proven (though, unlike the OP, I am merely curious about it at this stage).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Well, $Re_i$ is a local ring (according to that site) and it should be easy it is exactly the localization of $R$ at the corresponding maximal ideal.